# Can I pass a cursor in a procedure?

Tags: sql

can I pass a cursor in a procedure?

```
CURSOR  BLT_CURSOR IS
SELECT  BLT.sol_id,
        BLT.bill_id,
        BLT.bank_id
FROM BLT;
```

Is my cursor.

```
Procedure abc(i want to pass the cursor here)
```

How do I do it.

Answer (score 13):

I am assuming you are using Oracle (it would appear so).

You can do this:

```
PROCEDURE abc( p_cursor IN SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
   v_sol_id blt.sol_id%TYPE;
   v_bill_id blt.bill_id%TYPE;
   v_bank_id blt.bank_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      FETCH p_cursor INTO v_sol_id, v_bill_id, v_bank_id;
      EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      ...
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Then use it:

```
DECLARE
   v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN v_cursor FOR
      SELECT  BLT.sol_id,
              BLT.bill_id,
              BLT.bank_id
      FROM BLT;
   abc (v_cursor);
   CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
```

However, note that the procedure abc needs to know the structure of the cursor, i.e. that it returns 3 columns of particular types.  If you wanted to be able to pass **any** cursor to the procedure then you'd need to look at using the DBMS_SQL package (and that's not trivial!)

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) (SQL Server 2008): The cursor data type can be used only on OUTPUT parameters. When you specify a cursor data type, the VARYING and OUTPUT keywords must also be specified. You can have multiple output parameters specified with the cursor data type.

Comment: So the answer to the original question in context of T-SQL is "no, you can't"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in MSSQL2005.  I don't know about 2008 or other platforms.

There's been several times I'd like to do it.  It would support a more modular architecture.  I could have a proc that performs a common process on a dataset but be able to pass a cursor to that dataset from a variety of other procedures.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answers the question ("NO"), and adds information as to why the question is important.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that suggests maybe using a view assumes the intention is to be able to execute two different algorithms with the results of the same query.  Of course this is one use of passing a cursor but for me I wanted to execute the same algorithm with the results of two different queries.  I had two procedures each with their own purpose and a meaningful name that happened to share the same algorithm based around different queries so each would open the cursor with the appropriate query and then call a common procedure to execute the algorithm.

So, why not pass in the SQL of the query as text have have the inner procedure open the cursor there?  Because if you do that and the SQL has any bound variables you would need to pass them in along with the text which then means the two (or more) queries need not only to return the same set of columns they must also take the same number and types of bound variables.  If you pass the cursor instead the cursor is opened and the variables bound in the context of the procedure where the SQL is declared but the rows processed in the context of the procedure to which the cursor is passed.

Comment: One might look for a way to avoid dynamic SQL to benefit from better plan caching... That's how I came across this question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding MS-SQL you cannot pass the cursor as the input parametre. You can pass the cursor as the output parametre only.  
What you can do is to pass the cursor select clause text as an input parametre. You might find the working piece of code below useful.

```
--Create the table and fill it with data
DROP   TABLE    dbo.StackOverflow_MyTable
GO
CREATE TABLE    dbo.StackOverflow_MyTable (
                MyChar      varchar(10),
                MyDate      datetime,
                MyNum       numeric(10,2)
                PRIMARY KEY (MyChar))
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.StackOverflow_MyTable SELECT 'A1', '2018-01-13', 123.45
INSERT INTO dbo.StackOverflow_MyTable SELECT 'B2', '2018-01-14', 123.46
INSERT INTO dbo.StackOverflow_MyTable SELECT 'C3', '2018-01-15', 123.47
GO
/* Create the procedure which returns the cursor variable based on select statement
   The cursor must be opened here. Otherwise it throws an Error:
   The variable '@MyCursorVar' does not currently have a cursor allocated to it
*/
DROP   PROCEDURE dbo.StackOverflow_OpenCursor
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StackOverflow_OpenCursor @SelectSQL nvarchar(128), @MyCursorVar CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
    AS
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(256)
    SET @SQL='  SET     @MyCursorVar = CURSOR FOR '+@SelectSQL+'
                OPEN    @MyCursorVar'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@MyCursorVar CURSOR OUTPUT', @MyCursorVar OUTPUT
GO

--Create the procedure which browses the table using the cursor variable
DROP   PROCEDURE dbo.StackOverflow_BrowseCursor
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StackOverflow_BrowseCursor @SelectSQL nvarchar(128)
    AS
    --Create the cursor variable based on select statement and OPEN the cursor
    DECLARE @MyCursorVar CURSOR
    EXEC dbo.StackOverflow_OpenCursor @SelectSQL, @MyCursorVar OUTPUT

    --Declare the variables corresponding to table column
    DECLARE @MyChar varchar(10), @MyDate datetime, @MyNum numeric(10,2)
    --Browse record by record
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursorVar INTO @MyChar, @MyDate, @MyNum
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK
        PRINT @MyChar   --Here you might call any other procedure or dataset update
        PRINT @MyDate
        PRINT @MyNum
    END
    --release the cursor resources
    CLOSE       @MyCursorVar
    DEALLOCATE  @MyCursorVar
GO

--How to call the cursor browsing 
DECLARE @SelectSQL nvarchar(128)
SET     @SelectSQL = 'SELECT MyChar, MyDate, MyNum FROM dbo.StackOverflow_MyTable ORDER BY MyChar'
EXEC dbo.StackOverflow_BrowseCursor @SelectSQL
```