# can cursors be passed with parameters at execution time

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

can cursors be passed parameters dynamically?

for eg :

```
create or replace procedure getRec
as
cursor get(nameToGet varchar2) is select * from test where name = nameToGet;
rec test%rowtype;
begin
for rec in get('sam') loop
if get%notfound then
dbms_output.put_line('No record found');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Name : ' || ' ' || rec.name ||' ::: ' || 'Address : ' 
|| rec.address);
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

but this is hard coded (value of 'nameToGet'). How can I dynamically pass value to a cursor (if possible)?
Ofcourse we can do it using a parameterised procedure like

```
create or replace procedure getRec(nameToGet IN varchar2)
```

and the cursor would be like

```
cursor get is select * from test where name = nameToGet;
```

but I want to create a parameterised cursor and dynamically pass the value to the cursor.

Also on the other hand the dbms_output('record not found') does not execute when record not found. can anyone rectify the code?

Comment: I am a little rusty with PLSQL, but I think that the command to get the next record is `FETCH`, not `GET`. As for passing the **VALUE**, your question suggests that you want to do exactly what you are showing. Try to rephrase it so it is clearer.

Comment: @FDavidov 'get' here is the name of the cursor . Fetch is a keyword which is meant to fetch values from the cursor into declared variables.

Comment: Well, that is something beyond my recollections. As stated, I'm rusty. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: No problem... plsql is simple but the thing is when we go out of touch its really hard to recollect...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass a cursor in a procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368338/can-i-pass-a-cursor-in-a-procedure)

Comment: Indeed, though I don't recall ever using cursors the way you are. If I needed to perform selective operations from a table, I used table variables. Easier.

Comment: @Lagos Arpad no its not a duplicate.. my requirement is diff from the above mentioned link query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the procedure argument into the cursor if you want:

```
create or replace procedure getRec(nameToGet IN varchar2)
as
cursor get(nameToGet varchar2) is select * from test where name = nameToGet;
begin
for rec in get(nameToGet) loop
...
```

You might find it less confusing if you give the arguments different names, e.g. have a convention of procedure argument names starting with a 'p' prefix, cursor arguments starting with a 'c' prefix, or whatever.

And I've taken out the `rec` variable defitiion because that is never used; the `rec` in `for rec in ...` is a completely unrelated variable.

All of your `dbms_output` logic is inside the cursor for loop, so will only be evaluated within the loop - i.e. when there is data. If you want to use this loop construct you could use a flag to note whether you have been into the loop at all, something like:

```
create or replace procedure getRec(pNameToGet IN varchar2)
as
  cursor get(cNameToGet varchar2) is
  select * from test where name = cNameToGet;
  lDataSeen boolean := false;
begin
  for rec in get(pNameToGet) loop
    lDataSeen := true;
    dbms_output.put_line('Name : ' || ' ' || rec.name ||' ::: ' || 'Address : ' 
      || rec.address);
  end loop;

  if !lDataSeen then
    dbms_output.put_line('No record found');
  end if;
end;
```