# Oracle 11g PLSQL Convert rowtype to Varchar2 (or other sql type) and Back to Rowtype

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i need something to give a rowtype type to a Function with varchar2 input Parameter and convert it back to rowtype later in Oracle 11g PLSQL routines.

I want to write a Funktion Wrapper that does various things before calling a Funktion given as Parameter dynamicaly with Parameters.

I have no Problem for normal Parameters but i can't get it to run when i need to give a rowtype as Parameter. I can give alle Columns separatly as Parameter but that isn't a good option.

Now i search for a way to Convert the rowtype to something like varchar2, and in the dynamically called funktion convert it back to rowtype so i have all values.

hope there is a good way.

EDIT:

@ Lukasz Szozda: Passing Cursor is nice but i need the actual row that is looped through.

@William Robertson: Not possible. The Funktion is an Wrapper like i sayd before it is called for unknown tables. I can't define it before. I don't know the table from the rowtype before. Only the Calling Function and the dynamically called function know it but not the Wrapper function between them.

Comment: Passing cursor? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368338/can-i-pass-a-cursor-in-a-procedure

Comment: You should be able to pass a record type as a parameter. What isn't working exactly? Trying to convert a record to a string and back without losing details is going to be quite complicated.

Comment: @ Lukasz Szozda: Passing Cursor is nice but i need the actual row that is looped through.

@William Robertson: Not possible. The Funktion is an Wrapper like i sayd before it is called for unknown tables. I can't define it before. I don't know the table from the rowtype before. Only the Calling Function and the dynamically called function know it but not the Wrapper function between them.

Comment: If you pass a cursor you can parse it dynamically with dbms_sql.

Comment: Ok William Robertson, I go with you. And now you say me how i can bind the cursor to a dynamic function call with dbms_sql. If you don't find a solution like me i say it again: Cursor isn't a useable option.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?  The amount of detail provided so far leaves a lot of ambiguity.

Comment: I agree, this is a very vague question. Why isn't a cursor an option? It's the best way to deal with queries that return types not known at compile time.